# How to make sure a file is completed before copying it?

Tags: python, file, copy

An application A (out of my control) writes a file into a directory.
After the file is written I want to back it up somewhere else with a python script of mine.

Question: how may I be sure that the file is completed or that instead the application A is still writing the file so that I should wait until its completion? I am worried I could copy a partial file....

I wanted to use this function `shutil.copyfile(src,dst)` but I don't know if it is safe or I should check the file to copy in some other way.

Comment: this is OS dependent, and generally tricky enough on all platforms :)

Comment: please be specific: is the disk a local disk? what's the platform? windows, linux, other?

Comment: There is no external way to verify that A is done writing to the file; A is free to reopen it at any time. You need some way for *A* to state that it is done writing the file. Typically, this is done by A not writing directly to the final file, but to a temporary file that it moves into place *atomically* once it has finished writing. If you actually see the expected file, that is the evidence that A is done with it.

Comment: Had a similar situation but the application was writing multiple files in succession, so the solution I came up with was to simply monitor the directory and watch for changes in the existing files. As soon as `file2` was created, I knew that `file1` was ready to move.

Comment: If A is short-lived, you could have the backup process confirm that A isn't running before copying the file.

Comment: can't you use threads? isn't it classic producer-consumer problem? After A has completed it's writing can't it signal to thread of backup which will then wake up and take backup?.wait,notify,notifyall may be.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions. I am thinking about checking the filesize, therefore to copy again the file if the sizes of src and dst do not match.

Answer (score 0):

In general, **you can't**.

Because you don't have the information needed to solve the problem.

If you have to know that a file was completely transferred/created/written/whatever successfully, the *creator* has to send you a signal somehow, because only the creator has that information.  From the receiving side, there's in general no way to infer that a file has been completely transferred.  You can try to *guess*, but that's all it is.  You can't in general tell a complete transfer from one where the connection was lost, for example.

So you need a signal of some sort from the sender.

One common way is to use a rename operation from something like `filename.xfr` to `filename`, or from an "in work" directory to the one you're watching.  Since most operating systems implement such rename operations atomically, if the sender only does the rename when the transfer is successfully done, you'll only process complete files that have been successfully transferred.

Another common signal is to send a "done" flag file, such as sending `filename.done` once `filename` has been successfully sent.

Since you don't control the sender, you can't *reliably* solve this problem by watching for files.